# Why I am getting error in the else part of my shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying the below script in which I am expecting to receive two files in the filesdir folder on date1. If the date is 1 then it should check if two files are received or not, so thats why I m trying to increment a counter "count" each time it iterates and checks the loop. If the date is 1 and file not received then it should wait for few seconds and check again(because surely files will get received). If date is not 1, then it should remove those files and come out of the while loop. I am trying the below.

```
day_of_month=$(date +%d)
export filesdir=/dir1/dir2/dir3
local count=0
numFilesReceived=0
while true; do
    files=$(find $filesdir -name '*.txt.gz' -type f -mmin -1)
    if [ "$day_of_month" == "1" ]; then
        if [ -f "$files" ]; then
            count=$((count + 1))
            break
            if [ "$numFilesReceived" == "$count" ]; then
                echo "All $count data received!"
                break 3
            fi
        fi
        else
            echo "No data received yet!" 
        fi
        fi
         else
        rm $files
    fi
     done
```

I am not getting what I exactly want. Instead getting errors in the if else part.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of your other question as the code is identical and none of the errors pointed out in the accepted answer have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The number of `fi`s should be equal to the number of `if`s. Currently you have too many `fi`s.

The structure of a single `if` expression with `else` is `if... then... else... fi`, not `if... then... fi... else... fi`.